# How to get function name from getEventListener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a website basket and what is the name of the function that gets fired when clicked. I got my EventListener list by using `getEventListener($0)`, and the following is the list but I cannot figure out how to find what event was fired on `mousedown`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in fact on the @mamady answer, you can get the name of the function that get fired on mouseDown using `getEventListener($0).mousedown[0].listener.name` with Chrome dev tools.

As you see, probably the function name does not appears beacause it does not have a named function, so the function is annonymous, but you can see the location of the function:

[image]

If it's not, you can see the name of the function:

[image]

If the main problem is another (you have to get the name of the function to do something, what something?), please comment here.

Comment: As you might see, in my screenshot, the listener is t and everything value is t, on second one (first array), I was able to find a anonoymus function, clicking that took me the file and it highligted this `doAction: function(e) {this._doAction(e)}` and I am not sure what to make of it or how to create a event that will fire this event as I do not understand.

Answer (score -1):

Your description is quite different from the title. Do you want the function name that is bound to an event? Or do you want the event itself?

If you want the function name try this in your browser console:

```
  function asdasd(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', asdasd);
  let listeners = getEventListeners(button);
  console.log(listeners.mousedown[0].listener.name, "<- NAME OF THE FUNCTION");
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry if my title and body is confusing, I had Edit it, basically, I want to get the name of the function that get fired on mouseDown on a certain div, the js seem minified.

Comment: You can just use `getEventListener($0).mousedown[0].listener.name` to get the function name.

Comment: No property of `name` on `listener`